# Still pin image capture responding time

Tags: opencv, camera, video-streaming, directshow

I got a problem of the responding time of capturing an image from the still pin.

I have system running video stream at 320*480 from the capture pin and push a button to snap a 720P image from the still pin directly at the same time. But the responding time is too long, around 6 sec, which is not desirable.

I have try other video cap software support snapping a picture while video streaming, the responding time is similar.

I am wondering whether this a hardware problem or a software problem. And how the still pin capture is working actually.Is this from interpolation or change the resolution by hardware.

for example, the camera start at one resolution set keeps sensing and push the data to the buffer through the USB. is it possible for it immediately change to another resolution set and snap an image? is this why the system is taking picture slowly?

Or, is there a way to keep video streaming at high frame rate and snap a high resolution image immediately? No interpolation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am doing a project which has the function to snap a image from the video stream. The technology I use is DirectShow. And the responding time is not that long as yours. And the responding time has nothing to do with the streaming frame, according to my experience.

Usually a camera has its own default resolution. It is impossible for it mmediately change to another resolution set and snap an image. So that is not the reason.

Could you please show me some codes? And your camera's type ?

Comment: Hi，I understand the video streaming responding time. But I am trying the get data from the Still Pin, while keep video streaming from the capture Pin at the same time. Some Cameras got a Still and a capture pin. Check this out here, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318622%28v=vs.85%29.aspx .. However, the responding time is long, Other guys report the same problem as well. This should be a hardware related problem. Check the discussion here. http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsdirectshowdevelopment/thread/d8821119-a402-4c6a-a415-49ee5b6989e7